# Jquery Fade effect on Windows XP & Firefox 11

Tags: jquery, firefox, windows-xp, slider, fade

This is my first post!! :)

First, I'd like to thank this website's developers, it's awesome!

So, here we go:

I have a strange issue with jQuery sliders and the fade effect.
The Windows XP users have a black background on the fade effect instead of a transparent background.
I thought that the problem comes from my slider but the same issue appears on every slider I tried like this one:
http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow

I have no idea how to solve this :(

If you have a solution, it will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved.

I had this code for displaying a picture in my slider:

```
<img src="myimage.png" />
```

i replaced this by a `<div>` in which i put a background image, and the black screen is no longer !

Ha ve nice day !